# Static is not loading properly after cloning a Django project from git

Tags: django, nginx, server, static

Actually, I am hosting a project to a domain using a Linode server.
The Project is on Bitbucket.
I have tried all the methods static root static dirs and collect static but nothing works half of the CSS is loading but not left Static.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'static/')]
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

Nginx Config:

```
server {
server_name domain.in;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/web/tst/;
}
access_log /var/log/nginx/tst-access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/tst-error.log;
location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/web/msg/msg.sock;
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.in/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.in/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

}

```
server {
    if ($host = domain.in) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name domain.in;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: Share your nginx config

Comment: Edited in Question

Answer (score 0):

You have to server your static files through nginx and pass your static dir path to it:

```
server {
    ...
    location /static {    
        alias PATH_TO_YOUR_STATIC_DIR;    
    }
}
```

Comment: No That doesn't work add:  location /static {    
        alias 'home/web/tst/static';    
    }

Comment: Have you run `collectstatics` ? @ProudWadhwa

Comment: yes, I had tried each and every thing